# How to add credits to a public script

Tags: javascript, scripting

I like to share a script with other users. Is there a standard way to list the credits for a script that was created with help from a coding forum?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var _286277 = "__Created by some name__"

//you'll need to obfuscate the code below
if (_286277 === "__Created by some name__") {
console.log("very bad sample")
//code here
}
console.log("credits changed")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code-only answers but give a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. Also, IMHO this does not answer the original question as the OP asked for a generic way to deal with external credits.